# Software Center crash, sources.list error 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-center, software-sources

I'm having a problem with Software Center since I tried to add Spotify repositories to sources.list. It doesn't open at all.

I tried reinstalling Software Center, but it sends this error:

```
E:Type «http://repository.spotify.com» is not known on line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I'm not sure if this is the real problem, but apart from this everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to fix the broken lines.

To do this, run this command in a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find and comment or delete line 59. It should look like:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com ...
```

Save the file and quit the text editor. Then run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```